# Render same Partial view with different binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

On my website I have about 4 fields that need to be used up to 8 times. Currently I have all 8 fields on one view and then I use jQuery to show and hide each one if a link is clicked.

In my view model I have this

```
public class Example{
    public string String1 {get; set;}
    public string String2 {get; set;}
    etc..
}
public class MainClass{
    public Example example1 {get;set;}
    public Example example2 {get;set;}
    public Example example3 {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have something like this in my view

```
<div id=example1>
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.example1.String1)
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.example1.String2)
<!-- Link to load example 2 here --> 
</div>
<div id=example2>
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.example2.String1)
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.example2.String2)
</div>
```

Is there a way to find duplicate the view so I don't have 8 divs all rendered at page load?

Thanks

Comment: You can simplify it by using an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Example`, and then in the main view just use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.example1)`, `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.example2)` etc. Or better in `MainClass`, just have one property `List<Example> examples` and in the view its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.examples)` which will generate the controls for all items in the collection. However this will not add the `id` attribute to the enclosing `div` although its unclear what the point of that would be anyway.

Comment: The div id is there so that way they'd be able to be shown and hidden using javascript.

Comment: There are plenty of alternative ways to access the div other than giving it an `id` attribute but without seeing your script, impossible to tell what method would be best.